# hi, i am looking for a bash or pyton loop to run 10-20 commands and each time root password is required it will pass the hard coded password

Tags: python, bash, loops, subprocess, command

hi so tried couple of things like

python:

```py
import subprocess

commands = ['sudo -s', 'cd /', 'ssh user@host']

password = 'myRootPassword'

for command in commands:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Check if the command prompts for a password
    output, error = process.communicate()
    if 'password' in output.decode('utf-8').lower():
        # Send the password to the process
        process.stdin.write(password.encode('utf-8'))
        process.stdin.write(b'\n')
        process.stdin.flush()

    # Execute the command
    output, error = process.communicate()
    print(output.decode('utf-8'))
    print(error.decode('utf-8'))
```

This code throws an error on

```
    process.stdin.write(password.encode('utf-8'))
    process.stdin.write(b'\n')
    process.stdin.flush()
```

tried above code, but it throws an error ValueError

Comment: If you cannot get a sudo with NOPASSWD, and you must "type" in a password, look at `expect` for bash.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood `subprocess()`. Each call starts a ***new*** subprocess, so you can't do `cd /` in one and `ssh` in the next, because the first exits after`cd /` and the second starts in the current working directory of the calling process not of the exited process. Subprocesses are ***independent*** processes.